# Create Multiple charts using c3

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have  an API where am sourcing the data from.

Html snippet:

```
<div id='chart'></div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function PlotChart(chart_name,type,columns){
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: chart_name,
        data: {
            columns:columns,
            type: type
        },
        size: {
            width: 355.05
        }
    });
}
```

Using the above JavaScript as a skeleton for the charts, how do i pass in the API data into another function so that i can call the `PlotChart()` to create the multiple charts.

Create chart here:

```
function FirstOfTheManyCharts(){

  //Consume api data here

    plotChart('#chart', 'pie', columns);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FirstOfTheManyCharts(){

  //Consume api data here
function PlotChart(chart_name,type,columns){
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: chart_name,
        data: {
            columns:columns,
            type: type
        },
        size: {
            width: 355.05
        }
    });
}
    plotChart('#chart', 'pie', columns);

}
```

Comment: Not exactly how I want to do it. The PlotChart function is a mere skeleton to produce uniform chart-properties. However, the data from the API is different and am processing it differently for each chart.  So am looking for a way to have independent functions consuming the API data and calling the PlotChart function to create the charts

Comment: You can make a .js file and include it and then you can simply call the method passing the parameters.